# How can i get id or username of facebook for the text with regex

Tags: regex, go, re2

In the string, data looks like this. This is actually a string not json

```
[
   {
      "node":{
         "id":"100084753152635",
         "url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/profile.php?id=100084753152635",
         "name":"Hannah"
      }
   },
   {
      "node":{
         "id":"100049247496610",
         "__isProfile":"User",
         "url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/sayar.tole.31",
         "name":"\u1010\u102d\u102f\u1038 \u101d\u1031 \u101c\u1004\u103a\u1038"
      }
   }
]
```

now my regex

`(?:https?:)?\/\/(?:www\.)facebook.com/(?:profile.php\?id=)?(?P<id>[0-9]+)`

I want to get id from that text or username

Comment: can you give a bit more information about what you intend to do with that string afterwards ?

Comment: I'm still not sure for now. I'm just testing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the string, and the `\/` is a backslash with a forward slash, you can use 3 capture groups:

```
{[^{}]*?"id":"(\d+)",[^{}]*\\/\\/www\.facebook\.com\\/(?:profile\.php\?id=)?(?P<id>[\w.]+)",[^{}]*"name":"([^"]+)"
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MNCkFK/1).

Else you can just match the `/` without any escaping

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8eH78d/1).